# Replace text in Microsoft access with VBA function

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to write a function in my Microsoft access application to return a blank string when a "-" or "null" is inputted, and when any other string is inputted it should return the original string.

This is what I have so far:

```
Public Function cleanOutput(inStr As String)

    If inStr = "-" Or inStr = "null" Then
        cleanOutput = ""
    Else
        cleanOutput = inStr
    End If

End Function
```

However this is not working.  I'm sure this is a very basic solution, however I have zero experience with VB programming, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.  Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: "Instr" is a reserved name in VB/VBA. Try using different variable name in your function. Also add Option Explicit to top of your module and Debug | Compile before running your code to find obvious problems

Comment: And debug.print of your function's variable wrapping it in double quotes to ensure your getting what you expect

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what "not working" means, but if "null" means a true *Null*, you can use:

```
Public Function cleanOutput(inStr As Variant) As String

    If Nz(inStr, "-") <> "-" Then
        cleanOutput = inStr
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: "null" is not a true Null value.  "null" is a text string that my database holds in some fields.

Comment: Then your function will work as is. Something else is going on.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the variable name from inStr to something else and everything worked as expected!